# Find value of digit in an integer (defined in hex)

Tags: java

I have an integer defined in hex, like:

```
int number = 0x000500000;
```

Is it possible to get the value of a digit? For example, I want to know the value of the 5th digit (reading from right to left, though either direction would work great for me). Something like:

```
public int valueOfDigit(int value, int position) {
    return value at position'th digit of value;
}
```

How can I do that? (Not sure if digit is the right term here, please correct me if wrong),

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you convert it to base 10 and then look for it? Or know bit manipulation :D

Comment: Digit is fine btw. it's still a number, same as any, you're just using a different radix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, a hex digit is 4 bits, so basically it's just a case of shifting and masking:

```
public static int valueOfDigit(int value, int position) {
    return (value >> (position * 4)) & 0xf;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just and it with `0`? `(value >> (position * 4)) & 0`

Comment: @noMAD: `and`ing with 0 _usually_ produces 0.

Comment: @Vlad: When you say usually produces 0, in what cases it doesn't?

Comment: @noMAD: I suspect the "usually" part of Vlad's comment was somewhat tongue-in-cheek...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Integer class:

```
Integer.toHexString(number).charAt(position)
```

where position is the digit you want to read

Comment: You'd need `charAt(position)`, and the meaning of `position` would change depending on the first non-zero bit in the input.

Comment: Thanks, updated to reflect the charAt issue. And as for the meaning of position changing, I assume you mean that the string operation wouldn't give you a fixed-width representation?

Answer (score 1):

```
int digitMask = 0XF * 16 ^ (position - 1);
return (value & digitMask) / (16 ^ (position -1))
```